# How do I use domain.find() as a test in Chapel

Tags: chapel

I have a domain of strings and I want to test for an elements.  The [find](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/builtins/internal/ChapelArray.html?highlight=find#ChapelArray.find) seems to be what I want, but it's giving me an error.

```
var names: domain(string);
names += "bob";
if !names.find("bob") {
  writeln("Where is Bob?")
}
```

produces an error

```
error: illegal access of iterator or promoted expression
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check for membership within a domain, you want to use `domain.member()`:

```
if !names.member("bob") {
  writeln("Where is Bob?")
}
```

As for your original example, there is no `domain.find()`, so your original example is actually getting promoted to `string.find()` on each element of the domain. [#8450](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/8450) describes this in more detail.

Comment: How does `names.member("bob")` react to an empty `names` domain?

Comment: it returns false